# PHP Configuration file won’t load IIS7 x64

Tags: php, iis-7, fastcgi

using Fast CGI I can't get it to read the php.ini file. See my phpinfo below.

```
System Windows NT WIN-PAFTBLXQWYW 6.0 build 6001
Build Date Mar 5 2009 19:43:24
Configure Command cscript /nologo configure.js "--enable-snapshot-build" "--enable-debug-pack" "--with-snapshot-template=d:\php-sdk\snap_5_2\vc6\x86\template" "--with-php-build=d:\php-sdk\snap_5_2\vc6\x86\php_build" "--disable-zts" "--disable-isapi" "--disable-nsapi" "--with-pdo-oci=D:\php-sdk\oracle\instantclient10\sdk,shared" "--with-oci8=D:\php-sdk\oracle\instantclient10\sdk,shared" "--enable-htscanner=shared"
Server API CGI/FastCGI
Virtual Directory Support disabled
Configuration File (php.ini) Path C:\Windows
Loaded Configuration File (none)
Scan this dir for additional .ini files (none)
```

My php.ini file is residing in both my c:\php and my c:\windows I've made sure it has read permissions in both places from network service.

I've added various registry settings, Environment Variables and followed multiple tutorials found on the web and no dice as of yet. Rebooted after each.

My original install was using MS "Web Platform Installer" however I have since rebooted.

Comment: This question might find better answers on serverfault.com

Comment: It's on serverfault and there is not a solution there either

Comment: did anyone ever figure this one out? i am having the same problem.  the php.ini file has the correct permissions, located in the correct path, but it won't load...according to phpinfo()

Answer (score 1):

When I've had trouble loading php.ini files I found the following settings the key to getting it done.

```
--with-config-file-path=<path-to-php.ini> --sysconfdir=<path-to-php.ini>
```

In my case (on Linux) it was

```
./configure .....   --with-config-file-path=/etc --sysconfdir=/etc
```